# How to create if statement on the fly?

Tags: vim, input, if-statement

I want to create an IF statement with the help of a value from an inputdialog

example:
- value provided in inputdialog: "`>300`"
- I assigned this value to the variable "`a`"

My If statement has to be

```
   if temp >300   
     then  
   else  
     then  
   endif
```

How can I construct the IF statement with the help of the inputdialog variable?
"`if temp a`" doesn't work.

**EDIT**
This is my list:

```
mylist['1', '2000000', '32000', '33000', '8.40', '8.50', '8.8', '9.20']
```

using:

> for i in range....
>   if eval('mylist[i]' .a)

and
a = '<8.30'

This is the output:

```
mylistoutput['1', '8.40', '8.50', '8.8']
```

It seems that <8.30 is seen as <9

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `eval()` function, as follows.

```
if eval('temp' . a)
```

When evaluating user input, as usual, be careful of potentially dangerous
actions.

Comment: What would be the eval() function if I want to check `temp` if `a` has 2 paramters p.e. `>100 && <500` ?

Comment: found the solution. ;) - `if eval('temp' .a1) || eval('temp' .a2)`

Comment: I thought it was the answer but it doesn't work when `temp` and `a` is a float.

Comment: ib, please see my first message after EDIT.

Comment: @Remonn:  The comparison in the updated question does not work as you expect because your list contains *strings*, not numbers.  Thus, lexicographic string comparison is performed.  In order to parse a floating-point number from a string, use the `str2float()` function:  `if eval('str2float(t)'.a)`.

Comment: Wow... you're great!!! I tried this many times but without the quotes around str2float. :) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Several snippet plugins exist for this purpose:

- [ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715)

  - http://www.sirver.net/blog/2011/12/30/first-episode-of-ultisnips-screencast/
- [snipmate.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), see screencast:

  - http://vimeo.com/3535418

IIRC UltiSnips has more requirements (Vim 7.3 + Python3). I use SnipMate until now

---

Frankly, these snippet plugins use far superior template placeholder techniques to achieve what you describe.

Personally, having input dialogs like that would make me wish for Notepad.exe if I had to work with them

Comment: Yes, I know these snippet plugins but how can I resolve my question?